# Error running script in Google Apps Script for Documents

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have been trying to create a script with Google Apps Script for Documents. Until then the solution ran perfectly, but since last night I have received an error message when running my script as follows:Exception: ***The Documents service failed to access the document with the code 1tk-eeaBSSJ9Im2b5Y-e1jL8t18rKFXhp356udoyx8wA. (line 124, file "FindAttributes")***. After I inverted the method call the error changed to: ***GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with the error Invalid requests [0] .updateTableCellStyle: The provided table start location is invalid. (line 83, file "FindAttributes")***.
I searched the internet for any reference to this type of error, but my searches resulted in nothing.
My code checks for titles in a text and converts it to a certain custom format. What intrigues me is that it only occurs when it comes to the HEADING1 style, which is the first to be accessed in my script. When I override this method from HEADING1, the others work without problems. Does anyone have any idea what may be going on? I find it strange because the codes are exactly the same, except for the style formatting part.

My code:

```js
function verifiStyle(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragrafs = body.getParagraphs();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < paragrafs.length; i++){
    var attr = paragrafs[i].getAttributes();
    
    for(var at in attr){
      if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING1"){
        VerifTitle1(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING2"){
        VerifTitle2(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING3"){
        VerifTitle3(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING4"){
        VerifTitle4(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "NORMAL"){
        VerifTextoNormal(i);
      }
    }
  }
}

function VerifTitle1(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 20;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 10
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(40);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTitle2(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 15;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 10
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(40);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTitle3(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 10
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(40);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTitle4(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 10
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(40);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
  table.getRow(0).setMinimumHeight(0.2);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTextoNormal(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  
  var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Arial';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE] = 15;
  
  para[value].setAttributes(styleCell);
}
```

This is the result of my script when VerifiTitle1 () is enabled.

[image: one run]

This is the result when VerifiTitle1 () is disabled.
[image: second run]

That is. With this method inaccessible. everything goes well.

Comment: Translate errors into English please.

Comment: Have you enabled the Google Docs API in the GCP?

Comment: Yes, I activated the Google Docs API in the GCP.
What I find strange is that the other functions work normally. Only the first "VerifiTitle1" is in trouble, the strange thing is that the code is similar for all, except for some style settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

I think that the reason of your issue is to use `for(var i = 0; i < paragrafs.length; i++)` and `removeChild()`. In this case, the child is removed from the top of Document body. By this, the children of Document body is changed. So for example, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script in `verifiStyle()` as follows.

From:

```
for(var i = 0; i < paragrafs.length; i++){
```

To:

```
for(var i = paragrafs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
```

Comment: In general your solution worked well for me. The only observation I have to make is that the font-family, font-size and foregroudcolor formatting worked only for the last elements of the list. The other elements took the title type and border formatting only. Can you tell me what's going on?

Comment: @Leonardo Silva Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I cannot understand about it from your replying. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.